# MemoryStream for PictureBox from webcam

Tags: c#, webcam

I'm trying to snap a picture from webcam then add the picture i have just snapped to a table inside a database:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
P_Picture.Image.Save(ms,P_Picture.Image.RawFormat);
byte[] a = ms.GetBuffer();
ms.Close();
sql.ex.Parameters.Clear();
sql.ex.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", a);
sql.ex.CommandText = "insert into p_pictures  (P_ID,picture) values ('" + p_ID + "',@picture)";
sql.ex.Connection = sql.connection;
sql.ex.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but every time it test my code i get this error

[image: The error]

and it has been 3 hours searching for a solution. Does

Comment: Whats the actual format of the image?

Comment: Solution is "P_Picture.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);"